# Do all points along the world line of B need to be taken into account when finding the electric 4-force on A at proper time $\tau$, from B?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, spacetime

I understand that one way to understand special relativity is to consider a Universe with a spacetime metric of $(++++)$ and then figure out how to adjust equations and concepts for the $(---+)$ metric.  I understand that 4-velocity is the second derivative of spacetime coordinates with respect to proper time, and 4-acceleration is the derivative of 4-velocity with respect to proper time, and 4-force is the 4-acceleration multiplied by the rest mass.  I understand that conservation of energy, and momentum still apply in special relativity, implying that the 4-force on A from B must be equal and opposite the 4-force on B from A.

In the $(++++)$ spacetime metric if the concept of all inertial reference frames applies, and the concept of equal and opposite 4-forces applies, then in order to find the electric 4-force on particle A from particle B at proper time $\tau$ every point along the world line of particle B must be taken into account.

In special relativity, when finding the electric 4-force on particle A, at proper time $\tau$, from particle B, is it necessary to take into account all the points along particle B's world line, including those that have a time-like separation from particle A at proper time $\tau$?

Answer (score 1):

I'll focus on the final question, "is it necessary to take into account all the points along particle B's world line"? The answer is no. The electromagnetic field at A owing to B is determined purely by what B is doing at the moment when its worldline intersects the past lightcone of A. To be precise, the field at A depends on the location of that event (called the source event), and the charge, velocity and acceleration of B at that event.